# Writing a library that is optionally dependent on a third party library

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I want to create a Scala library (A) to provide some generic utility. Library A has no 3rd part dependencies. I also want to include some functionality B that depends on A and also on some 3rd party library C. Think of B as providing some extra utilities for C, based on A.

What is the best strategy to package and build A with B? I assume that the majority of users will not need B, so they won't need to know or install library C.  If I don't add C as a dependency to A+B, it won't compile.

I could make B into a separate project that depend on A and C. But is there a way make it as a "plugin" to B, so I won't need an additional project?

Comment: It's entirely possible to do what you're describing with plain old runtime reflection. I know, because I've used libraries that went that route, and it has always been an incredibly miserable experience. That said, it's a good question, even if just using two projects is a better idea in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. There are some horrible hacky approaches like multiple maven artifacts or the big black pit of OSGi packaging, but users will not thank you for doing those things; just making B a separate artifact that depends on A and C is by far the most userfriendly approach. Remember that you can have multiple modules in the same codebase that are released and versioned together, using a [maven multi-module project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) or similar support in SBT.